# How to detect memory limit of os.system

Tags: python, memory-management

I'm currently setting up and running a number of commands with os.fork and os.system commands. I set the time and memory limits through resource.setrlimit, and that seems to be working fine. However, each program has it's own way of crashing because of a memory cap -- a python program throws a MemoryError, a c++ program may have a bad alloc, etc.

What I would like to know is how I can detect when an os.system command has finished executing because of a memory limit restriction (as supposed to a timeout or some other manner of completing). I've tried the following without success:

```
try:
    status = os.system(command)
except MemoryError:
    # Never actually makes it here...
```

**Edit**: I'm really only concerned with unix systems for now.

Comment: From the doc "On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return value of the Python function is system-dependent." So maybe you can do a dict that maps these values to the actual errors in your own system.

Comment: Wouldn't those values be application dependent? i.e., the c++ developer could call exit(42) if (s)he felt like it, and I don't presume to know what that means.

Comment: Of course you have to make your code follow some standards. But that's true whenever you want two program to communicate correctly.

Comment: Aye, but the issue is that it isn't necessarily my code that is running out of memory. As such, I won't have control over the convention used for return codes.

Comment: Where does the code come from?

Comment: I'm creating this for a library that allows others to empirically test their software (cross product of parameter settings, etc). The actual programs that will be tested is entirely up to the user of the library (not me).

Comment: In that case you can't do anything you have to agree with the people who develop the program underneath.

Comment: Just curious --- what do you need this for?

Comment: lc2817: Thanks -- I'll just be sure to document it well then.

Ondrej: I often need to evaluate the efficiency of my software when using different configuration settings, and over a set of benchmark input problems. The library I'm developing lets you test things in a convenient way, providing memory / time bounds, using multiple cores, etc. The reason I raised this question is because I want a better method for detecting memory issues so it's easier on the user creating an experimental setup (i.e., they don't need to parse / look for the errors themselves).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://blog.tsul.net/2008/04/ossystem-and-its-return-value.html

On windows it seems that system() and wait() both always return 0.

On unix or mac, system() will return "a tuple containing its pid and exit status indication: a 16-bit number, whose low byte is the signal number that killed the process, and whose high byte is the exit status (if the signal number is zero); the high bit of the low byte is set if a core file was produced. Availability: Macintosh, Unix."

You should be able to look at the low byte to see if what the signal is and use that to determine the reason it was killed / exited.

Comment: Signal number appears to always be 0, but the exit code varies and seems to only be 0 when it runs nominally...testing to see if this works for all the cases I have.

Comment: Seems to work for what I'm dealing with. I'll need to change the behaviour to mean either a timeout occurred or "something bad" occurred (which includes a memory failure) -- the exit code varies from program to program unfortunately (but 0 always indicates successful completion).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a system call like that is unlikely to wrap the return value and raise an exception.

you will have to do that yourself with the subprocess module: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

however, depending on what system call you make, you may not know if it fails due to memory error unless it explicitly tells you it did.